# Unable to render response in html format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am facing trouble displaying an Html document as a response to my rails API.
The Html string is displayed as plain text, it seems like the tags are getting escaped even though I have used html_safe.

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render html: "<h1>Hello World</h1>".html_safe }
  end
```

This is the html DOM:

```
<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
&lt;h3&gt;Hello World&lt;/h3&gt;</pre></body></html>
```

On the web page, I expect to see just Hello World, but instead, this whole Html string is shown.

I have also tried with a template file (.html.erb) but the result is the same.

Rails version: 4.2

Comment: Shouldn't `respond_with` be [`respond_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to)? I can't find `respond_with` in the [Rails 4.2 documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/).

Comment: Yes, you are right. respond_with was removed from version 4.2. Thanks for pointing out, have edited the question. However, I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Wait a second here. Why are you calling `render html:` with a string in the first place? If you have a static HTML file you would render it with `render file: 'path/to/file.html'`. If not you really should just create a view which contains your HTML.

Comment: And also "On the web page, I expect to see just Hello World, but instead, this whole Html string is shown.". What you are sending back to the browser is not a valid HTML document. And the browser is kicking into full blown slop mode to process it. The results will be very unpredictable. Look at the source of the page if you want to see what rails is really sending back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `respond_to`

```
render html: '<h1>Hello World</h1>'.html_safe
```

POSTMAN:
[image: postman response]

BROWSER:

[image: response in browser]

Comment: Can you post an image of what you are getting? Because I am getting `Hello World` as expected when making request via Postman so it should be working as expected in the browser too. I will add the image of what I am getting in answer. Comment doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: Can you share the full response that you are getting in postman?

Comment: Raw format response would be `<h1>Hello World</h1>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211373/discussion-between-sjana-and-prabin-poudel).

Comment: "As expected" is extremely relative when you're talking about a document this malformed.